# CSS Color site with links taken into account?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I'm having trouble deciding on the color scheme for my site, in that I've chosen the `background-color` and `color` but the way links look in their varied states visited,hover etc don't coordinate well with my main colors.

I know how to control the colors on links:

```
a:link
{
    color: #66FF33;
}
a:visited
{
    color: #FF0000;
}
a:hover
{
    color: #FFFF66;
}
a:active
{
    color: #66FF33;
}
```

My problem is juggling 6 colors in my head, the 2 main ones and the 4 for links, to see if they clash  when I change one etc , I know there are a lot of sites to help you choose a color scheme, is there one which takes into account the visited, hover etc links in their preview/generate CSS functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just load the page you are trying to mess around with in a web browser and use Firebug to alter your CSS and test different colors.
Make yourself a sample HTML page containing links to visited and unvisited sites.  Add a table with cells that you can alter the colors and play with it in the browser.

Comment: Yes that's always a option, but I was hoping there was a site which has this functionality I described to speed up the process by having dials and such, I know there are sites for doing this already I'm just interested if there is one which takes links and their pseudo-classes into account that's the big problem for me.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because as far as I can tell there's no site which does what I want, at least until I write one :P, and I'm going to do it the manual way as described in this post.

Answer (score 1):

```
Choose colors that do not overlap themselves, and avoided as much as you can the too many colors, unless if this is the concept.
Webpages are often designed in 2-3 basic, contrasted or complementary colours. 
For starters, it is good to counsel websites that offer combinations but occasionally it is good to try and develop your own style.
Do not forget to research the well-designed pages on the internet,
as aesthetics is something dynamic.
The main thing is the content and the character of the site that will determine
and the aesthetics and color.
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, as I said my main problem is with the links I can chose a 2-3 basic theme it's just that the default pseudo classes always get in the way for me, and as I said I can control them but that means 4 other distinct colors which complicates everything.